# How to fill three EditText one by one using Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This code is working very well. I want it more simply like using `nextFocusLeft`, `nextFocusRight` and `nextFocusForward`. My code contains a lot of if and if else.

```java
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
            //my buttons
                Button b1, b2,b3;
                //my Empty editText to fill them by my buttons one by one
                EditText t1,t2,t3;

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



                    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
                    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
                    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);



                    t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t1);
                    t2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t2);
                    t3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t3);

                    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
                    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
                    b3.setOnClickListener(this);




                }


                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    switch (view.getId()){
                        case R.id.b1:


                         //check if editText Empty or not
                            if (t1.getText().toString().equals("")){

                                t1.setText(t1.getText().toString() + b1.getText());

                            }else if (t2.getText().toString().equals("")){

                                t2.setText(t2.getText().toString() + b1.getText());
                            }else if (t3.getText().toString().equals("")){

                                t3.setText(t3.getText().toString() + b1.getText());
                            }

                            break;


                        case R.id.b2:

                           //check if editText Empty or not

                            if (t1.getText().toString().equals("")){

                                t1.setText(t1.getText().toString() + b2.getText());

                            }else if (t2.getText().toString().equals("")){

                                t2.setText(t2.getText().toString() + b2.getText());
                            }else if (t3.getText().toString().equals("")){

                                t3.setText(t3.getText().toString() + b2.getText());
                            }

                            break;


                        case R.id.b3:

                           //check if editText Empty or not

                            if (t1.getText().toString().equals("")){

                                t1.setText(t1.getText().toString() + b3.getText());

                            }else if (t2.getText().toString().equals("")){

                                t2.setText(t2.getText().toString() + b3.getText());
                            }else if (t3.getText().toString().equals("")){

                                t3.setText(t3.getText().toString() + b3.getText());
                            }

                            break;




                    }
                        //check Answer 
                       //correct answer ABC
                        if (t1.getText().toString().equals("A") &&
                            t2.getText().toString().equals("B") &&
                            t3.getText().toString().equals("C") ){

                       //if answer correct do
                        t1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
                        t2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
                        t3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);


                    }


                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit better..

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    final Button button = findViewById(view.getId());
    final String text = button.getText();

    //check if editText Empty or not
    if (t1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        t1.setText(t1.getText().toString() + text);
    }else if (t2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        t2.setText(t2.getText().toString() + text);
    }else if (t3.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        t3.setText(t3.getText().toString() + text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it does it works beacuse when I click on button3 it typing in editText3 skip editText1 and editText2 , i want check if editText1 Empty when I click button1 ,button2 and button3

Comment: I havent changed the conditions of the if else statements, its exactly the same code just not repeated 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

```
       t1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            t2.requestFocus();
        }
    });
```

Comment: can i get more detials : my buttons b1,b2,b3 my EditText  t1,t2,t3